# Share Dialog (PHOTO) of Facebook SDK is not working

Tags: android, facebook, share

i tried the following code

```
 List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
                list.add(new File(uri.getPath()));
                boolean canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(mContext, FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.PHOTOS);
                Log.d(TAG, "canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos: " + canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos);

                if (canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos) {
                    // Publish the post using the Photo Share Dialog
                    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder((Activity) mContext)
                            .addPhotoFiles(list)
                            .build();
                    shareDialog.present();
                } else {}
```

i am getting canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos value true

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider1576508475912674"
        android:exported="true" />
```

replace "1576508475912674" by your fbID